# Error in nodejs prevents the use of simple codes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I encountered an issue while writing a simple code snippet in Node.js. I attempted to assign a value to a variable, and it resulted in an error. Here's the code I wrote:

```
var nome = 'Pedro'

var idade = 28

var sexo = 'masc'

nome + ' é do sexo ' + se
```

However, before finishing writing the variable sexo, it displayed the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.PowerShell_7.3.6.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\pwsh.exe[12740]: c:\ws\src\inspector\node_string.cc:49: Assertion `(expected_utf16_length) == (utf16_length)' failed.

 1: 00007FF72674BC8F node_api_throw_syntax_error+203199

 2: 00007FF7266C81D6 v8::base::CPU::num_virtual_address_bits+74438

 3: 00007FF7266C85E2 v8::base::CPU::num_virtual_address_bits+75474

 4: 00007FF726571BCF uv_loop_size+57695

 5: 00007FF72658BFC7 uv_loop_size+165207

 6: 00007FF726589496 uv_loop_size+154150

 7: 00007FF72657CEE7 uv_loop_size+103543

 8: 00007FF7270E7B2E v8::SharedValueConveyor::SharedValueConveyor+416270

 9: 00007FF7270E772A v8::SharedValueConveyor::SharedValueConveyor+415242

10: 00007FF7270E79EF v8::SharedValueConveyor::SharedValueConveyor+415951

11: 00007FF7270E7860 v8::SharedValueConveyor::SharedValueConveyor+415552

12: 00007FF7271E228E v8::PropertyDescriptor::writable+674286

13: 00007FF6A7317277
```

I have already taken the following steps to troubleshoot the issue:

I reinstalled the LTS version of Node.js.
I installed the additional tools for Node.js.
I updated PowerShell to the latest version.
I restarted my computer.
Despite these efforts, the error still persists. I would appreciate any guidance on how to resolve this issue. Thank you!

Comment: How are you trying to execute your code? `node myFile.js`? It runs perfectly fine when I try it.

Comment: @Mushroomator it *might* be because OP's code has a combining diacritic for the `é` instead of the NFC normalized character and it's being normalized by Stack Overflow and thus works fine when you run it. That *shouldn't* matter, but seeing that V8 is complaining about an unexpected string length value in the JS source I'm wondering.

Comment: Pedr21, double-check the encoding of your Javascript source file.

Comment: I started learning JavaScript now, in the course I'm taking, the teacher explained a bit about variables using the Node.js terminal. I ran this code in both the Node.js terminal and the Visual Studio Code terminal. However, I am still facing the mentioned error.

Comment: Try putting it in a source file and run it that way as Mushroomator suggested, and/or try it with only ASCII characters